# How to make an input react the same way as the parent div in a flexbox?

Tags: html, css, input, flexbox

I'm trying to size some divs correctly with a flexbox, so that the inputs and the other items that I'm going to add in later have the correct sizes, but no matter what I do to the div, the input size doesn't change.

What can I do to the input to make it so that it's size also changes according to the parent div?

Below I posted the code I have currently, along with the same code with an obviously small input. The second one shows the green area with the correct sizes with the small inputs, while on the one on top, the inputs stretch the parent out and all have the same size...

I need to keep the sizes marked in green by the second one, and I want the inputs to match that size...

```css
.flex-o-1 {flex: 1 1 auto;}
.flex-o-2 {flex: 2 2 auto;}
.flex-o-3 {flex: 3 3 auto;}
.flex-o-4 {flex: 4 4 auto;}
.flex-o-5 {flex: 5 5 auto;}

.GenInfo {display: flex;}

.GenInfo>div {
  margin-left: 0.2em;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  background-color: green;
  height: 2em;
}

.GenInfo>div>input {max-width: 100%;} /* Also tried without this, nothing changes */

.SmallInput {max-width: 1em !important;} /* !important just for testing */
```

```html
<div class="GenInfo">

  <div class="flex-o-5">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>

  <div class="flex-o-1">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>

  <div class="flex-o-3">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>

  <div class="flex-o-2">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>

  <div class="flex-o-2">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>

  <div class="flex-o-4">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>

</div>
<br>
<div class="GenInfo">

  <div class="flex-o-5">
    <input type="text" class="SmallInput" />
  </div>

  <div class="flex-o-1">
    <input type="text" class="SmallInput" />
  </div>

  <div class="flex-o-3">
    <input type="text" class="SmallInput" />
  </div>

  <div class="flex-o-2">
    <input type="text" class="SmallInput" />
  </div>

  <div class="flex-o-2">
    <input type="text" class="SmallInput" />
  </div>

  <div class="flex-o-4">
    <input type="text" class="SmallInput" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply a small width then use `min-width:100%`

```css
.flex-o-1 {flex: 1 1 auto;}
.flex-o-2 {flex: 2 2 auto;}
.flex-o-3 {flex: 3 3 auto;}
.flex-o-4 {flex: 4 4 auto;}
.flex-o-5 {flex: 5 5 auto;}

.GenInfo {display: flex; margin-bottom:5px}

.GenInfo>div {
  margin-left: 0.2em;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  background-color: green;
  height: 2em;
}


.GenInfo>div>input {
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="GenInfo">

  <div class="flex-o-5">
    <input type="text" >
  </div>

  <div class="flex-o-1">
    <input type="text" >
  </div>

  <div class="flex-o-3">
    <input type="text" >
  </div>

  <div class="flex-o-2">
    <input type="text" >
  </div>

  <div class="flex-o-2">
    <input type="text" >
  </div>

  <div class="flex-o-4">
    <input type="text" >
  </div>

</div>
<div class="GenInfo">

  <div class="flex-o-5">
  </div>

  <div class="flex-o-1">
  </div>

  <div class="flex-o-3">
  </div>

  <div class="flex-o-2">
  </div>

  <div class="flex-o-2">
  </div>

  <div class="flex-o-4">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Wow.. can't believe I only tried max-width and not width xD Thanks

Comment: Actually, while it seems to work at first, the sizes are all wrong still... It is progress, but still not what I wanted

Comment: @Nyss check again, It's fixed